# How to evaluate multiple values in the Contains function via a declarative salesforce formula

Tags: formula-field, contains

I am trying check if the suppliedemail field contains any of these domains but is not working.

```
If(CONTAINS("lincare.com:ndc-inc.com:preferredhomecare.com", SuppliedEmail),
            mod(value(CaseNumber),3)+1,0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work as you designed it as `SuppliedEmail` will look like `joeblogs@preferredhomecare.com` and that will never be contained inside the first arg of the CONTAINS.

Your approach works great for a problem wherein the matchKey will exist somewhere inside the first argument. For example, this stateCode match [from the doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.usefulFormulaFields.meta/usefulFormulaFields/useful_advanced_formulas_acct_mgmt.htm):

```
IF(ISBLANK(BillingState), "None",
IF(CONTAINS("AK:AZ:CA:HA:NV:NM:OR:UT:WA", BillingState), "West",
IF(CONTAINS("CO:ID:MT:KS:OK:TX:WY", BillingState), "Central",
IF(CONTAINS("CT:ME:MA:NH:NY:PA:RI:VT", BillingState), "East",
IF(CONTAINS("AL:AR:DC:DE:FL:GA:KY:LA:MD:MS:NC:NJ:SC:TN:VA:WV", BillingState), "South",
IF(CONTAINS("IL:IN:IA:MI:MN:MO:NE:ND:OH:SD:WI", BillingState), "North", "Other"))))))
```

You have a couple of options:

Option 1: (from [SteveMo answer](https://trailblazers.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gi8EAAQ))

Your matchkey needs to be just the domain portion of the email:

```
If(CONTAINS("lincare.com:ndc-inc.com:preferredhomecare.com", 
        SUBSTITUTE(SuppliedEmail, LEFT(SuppliedEmail, FIND("@", SuppliedEmail)), NULL),
        mod(value(CaseNumber),3)+1,0)
```

Option 2: Use REGEX